# .NET Core Repository storage per request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to track a list of specific changes made in some repositories that occur over the course of a request so that I can feed them back into my response (via an Action Filter).  I need a data store that lives for the duration of the request and that the repositories can access and manage what gets added to this list of changes, and then the Action Filter can read and append to the response.  Is HttpContext an appropriate solution for this, or is there a better option?

I've tried using various combinations of injecting HttpContext or IHttpContextAccessor into the Repositories but am having issues getting a working setup and am even wondering if this is the proper approach anymore.

Here is the flow I'm trying to achieve

- Incoming Request
- Controller processes request and calls function in repository
- Repository says "hey I want to add this to the response data for this request"
- Action filter appends necessary data to outgoing response

I need to track this throughout various business logic, so having the one function return data to the controller to be appended to the response would not be maintainable/sustainable.

Comment: I'd define my custom interface, like `IRequestSpecificStorage : IDisposable`; then inject this via IoC as `.AddScoped<>`; then inject into whatever needs it.
Hooking into `HttpContext` would work but it would feel counterintuitive to whoever comes after you to maintain that code